# template-template parameter giving mysterious type/value mismatch

Tags: c++, templates, template-templates

I am making a class Multistack, which should be called with either:

`Multistack<type>`

or

`Multistack<type, container>`

e.g.

`Multistack<int, vector>`

Below is my code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <list>

using namespace std;

template <typename T, template <typename> class Cont>
    class Multistack {
public:
    // Member functions

private:
    Cont<T> _elems;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    Multistack<int, vector> ms;
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
main9.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main9.cpp:18:27: error: type/value mismatch at argument 2 in template parameter list for ‘template<class T, template<class> class Cont> class Multistack’
     Multistack<int, vector> ms;
                           ^
main9.cpp:18:27: note:   expected a template of type ‘template<class> class Cont’, got ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
main9.cpp:18:29: warning: unused variable ‘ms’ [-Wunused-variable]
     Multistack<int, vector> ms;
```

I have found similar problems but none seem to have a solution that solves mine.

Comment: `Multistack` expects a one-parameter class template as its second argument. `std::vector` is a two-parameter template. Just take a type as the second parameter (as opposed to a template), and pass `std::vector<int>`

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik: Oh, do you know the correct syntax in the template, in order to be able to pass an `std::vector`? The thing is, I want the first argument to define the type, and the second argument to define the container. So the syntax for calling my constructor should be `Multistack<int, std::vector>`.

Comment: Well, for `std::vector` specifically, you could use `template <typename, typename> class Cont`, and use it as `Cont<T, std::allocator<T>>`. Though if you design a class that pretty much only works with `std::vector`, why bother taking a parameter at all?

Comment: I don't get it working. Perhaps I misunderstand something. May I ask you to post a solution? You can just copy paste my code and edit whatever necessary and indulge me a couple of comments on why the solution works. I would truly appreciate it @IgorTandetnik.

Comment: [This compiles](http://rextester.com/SKEKQ61219)

Comment: You sir, are a life saver!! Thank you @IgorTandetnik! Please post your code as a solution so I can click resolved, it may help someone in the future.

Comment: if you can use C++11 (or newer), you can define `Cont` as `template <typename...> class`; defining it only as `template <typename, typename> class` you intercept only `vector`, `deque`, `list`, `forward_list`, `stack` and `queue`; with `typename...` you intercept also `set`, `multiset`, `map`, `multimap`, `unordered_set`, `unordered_multiset`, `unordered_map`, `unordered_multimap` and `priority_queue`. But you don't intercept (with `typename, typename` or `typename...`) `array`

Comment: Very good @max66, I appreciate your input, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Declaration of [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is:

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

It doesn't match with the template-template parameter `template<typename> class Cont`.

Use the following instead:

```
template <typename T, template <typename...> class Cont>
class Multistack {
    // ...
};
```

This will give you the chance to use either `std::vector`, `std::list` and the others that have two template parameters as well as containers like `std::set` and `std::priority_queue` that have three or more template parameters. Of course, custom containers that has only one template parameter will be accepted as well.